# Array of custom objects for ItemsSource in XAML for design preview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to draw objects of a custom class on a `Canvas` with `ItemsControl`. To have some kind of **preview** in the VisualStudio **designer**, I'd add a `ItemsSource` with a `Collection` of some demonstration objects. But I cannot figure out how to declare a **collection of my objects**.

With `Point` I can use `PointCollection`:

```xml
<ItemsControl Name="pointsItems2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.5"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- Setting the position with a style is necessary. Setting parent properties in the template does not work -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <!-- The offset converter moves the center of the circle to the desired position. ConverterParameter is the offset.-->
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=OffsetConverter}, ConverterParameter='-5'}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=OffsetConverter}, ConverterParameter='-5'}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <PointCollection>
            <Point X="0"   Y="0"   />
            <Point X="10"  Y="10"  />
            <Point X="20"  Y="40"  />
            <Point X="30" Y="90" />
        </PointCollection>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now I have a class that has properties that I use as coordinates, but also other properties that I need later that need to have a graphical representation. So I want to change the literal specified ItemsSource to something that represents objects of my class.
I came up with

```xml
<x:Array Type="{x:Type Point}">
    <Point X="0" Y="0"/>
    <Point X="100" Y="100"/>
</x:Array>
```

The problem here is that when I want to instantiate my class, the **default constructor** would be called and I could set **properties via attributes**, but my class relies on **parametrized constructors** and public properties **no** have **public setters**.

How could that be accomplished in an elegant and WPF/XAML-like way?

Comment: You can create a dummy class in code behind and refer to that.

Comment: @Silvermind: I cannot figure out how to call the constructor of my custom class from that dummy. And still I do not know how it is supposed to work to get a preview without going to write lots of wrapper code. There must be a way WPF...

Answer (score 0):

Basically - you can't.  XAML 2009 supports passing constructor parameters but this doesn't work with WPF according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - at least not in the way you describe.  it can be in a XAML file included later, but not in a compiled file so I don't think it would work in the designer.

Why can't you create a parameterless constructor and change the properties to have public setters?

If there is a good reason for not, then maybe create a dummy holding class for the parameters and bind the ItemsSource to a collection of these dummy classes using a ValueConverter to go from the dummy class to the class you want.  This way you can construct in code and use the parameterized constructor.